# Conditional panels in sidebar of Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I know there are a few posts about this issue, but I'm not getting why my code is not working.  I have an app in Shiny that I'd like to have contain a conditional sidebar panel, that shows different controls based on which panel in the main panel is currently selected by the user.  I thought the code below would work, but the app only displays conditional panel 1 (as defined below).  Can anyone give me any advice?  Thanks.

my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Spatially Balanced Sampling Tool"),

  sidebarPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 175px; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea { max-width: 100px; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", ".jslider { max-width: 120px; }"),
      tags$style(type='text/css', ".well { max-width: 200px; }"),
      tags$style(type='text/css', ".span4 { max-width: 200px; }")
    ),

conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == 1",       
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose .ZIP Shapefile:', multiple=TRUE,
                           accept=c('binary'))
),

conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == 2", 
                   numericInput("pts", "# of sampling points per stratum:", 50),
                   numericInput("oversamppts", "# to OVER sample (optional):", 5),
                   submitButton("Generate Points"),
                 helpText("WORK DAMMIT")

)),

mainPanel(

tabsetPanel(

  tabPanel("Instructions",
           includeHTML("instructions.html"), 
           div(id="linkToMap", tags$a("Click here to see a map of your input data and create points")), 
           div(id="linkToPoints", tags$a("Click here to see table of created points")),
           value=1
  ),

  tabPanel("plot",  helpText("Map of input polygons"),
           plotOutput("plot"),
           p(paste("polygons by strata")),

           value=2
  ),
  tabPanel("View Points", helpText("suggested sampling points"),
           tableOutput("pointdata"),


           HTML("<script>$('#linkToMap').click(function() {
                tabs = $('.tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li')
                tabs.each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                })
                $(tabs[1]).addClass('active')
                tabsContents = $('.tabbable .tab-content .tab-pane')
                tabsContents.each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                })
                $(tabsContents[1]).addClass('active')

                $('#plot').trigger('change').trigger('shown')

                })</script>
                "),
           HTML("<script>$('#linkToPoints').click(function() {
                tabs = $('.tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li')
                tabs.each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                })
                $(tabs[2]).addClass('active')
                tabsContents = $('.tabbable .tab-content .tab-pane')
                tabsContents.each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                })
                $(tabsContents[2]).addClass('active')

                $('#pointdata').trigger('change').trigger('shown')

           })</script>
                "),
           value=2
           ),


id = "conditionedPanels"))))
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the conditionalPanel statement is looking for the *name* of the tabPanel.

```
 # This will not work
 condition="input.conditionedPanels == 1" #wrong
```

When I switched the condition in your `conditionalPanel` statement to test for the *name* of the tab, as opposed to the value, it worked.

I scooped out everything extraneous and got your UI.R to work conditionally as intended. You can use this as a starting point and go from here.

#### UI.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(  
  headerPanel("Spatially Balanced Sampling Tool"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == 'Tab1'",       
                     helpText("TAB 1")
    ),    
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == 'Tab2'", 
                     helpText("TAB 2 SELECTED")
                    )
    ),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab1",
               p(paste("Tab 1 text")                 
          )
      ),
      tabPanel("Tab2",  helpText("Map of input polygons"),
               p(paste("polygons by strata")
                 )
      ), 
      id = "conditionedPanels"                
        )
    )  
))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ram.. but that doesn't jive with the documentation I've seen?  Yet, I did try your suggestion, and i still got hte same faulty behavior as before.  I suspect now I have some sort of a bug brought out by some of the rest of my code.  I have a simpler app that I was able to get the conditional sidebar to work with the syntax/format of my original post.

Comment: The documentation does say that the conditionalPanel will evaluate for a JavaScript expression. You are right, the documentation could be clearer, but meanwhile the Shiny Google Group is wonderful. And yes, I suspect that some other line in the rest of your code is causing it not to work.

Comment: I notice that the addition of a submitButton() into either conditionalPanels will break the interaction. E.g.:     conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == 'Tab1'",       
                     helpText("TAB 1"),
                     submitButton()
    ),